# How to restrict an html input to positive decimal numbers up two decimals?

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I am writing a angularjs app and am trying to restrict an html tag to positive float numbers with up to 2 decimal places.

code I have now...

```
<input type='number' min='.01' ng-model='threshold' />
```

Comment: Are you using <input type="text" /> or <input type="number" />?

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far please.

Comment: <input type='number'>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `pattern` attribute to set a proper regular expression. For example:

```html
<input name="x" pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" placeholder="000.00" />
```

See [html5pattern.com](http://html5pattern.com).

Comment: This did not work when using input `type='text'` (on Chrome Version 114.0.5735).